# #upload_validators missing error message

Tags: 7, forms

### [Update]

Upon further investigation it seems that the message isn't appearing due to the following javascript error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

[image: javascript error]

[image: javascript error details]

I'm not sure how to resolve this error, but the following issues may be related:

- [[D7] Duplicate HTML IDs are created for file_managed_file fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/2594955#comment-10480932)
- [Duplicate HTML IDs are created for file_managed_file fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/2497909)

### Description

I'm trying to create a custom form with some number of file upload fields (for now I'm using the hard-coded value 3).

I have added an #upload_validators attribute to the managed_file element that calls file_validate_extensions and passes in "doc" as the only valid filetype.

When I try to upload a .jpg, an error appears -- which is what I want. However, the error doesn't contain any text.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

### Code

```
function mymodule_example1_form($form_state) {
  $num_docs = 3;

  // Build the number of name fieldsets indicated by $form_state['num_docs'].
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_docs; $i++) {
    $form['managed_file'][$i] = array(
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => 'Managed File' . $i,
      '#progress_indicator' => 'throbber',
      '#progress_message' => 'Upload successful!',
      "#upload_validators"  => array("file_validate_extensions" => array("doc")),
      '#upload_location' => 'public://doc/',
    );
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

### Screeshot

[image: empty form error]

### Resources

- [Drupal Form API Reference - managed_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#managed_file)
- [Drupal API - function file_validate_extensions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_validate_extensions/7.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue using the solution posted [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2594955#comment-10951475).

As I understand it, the issues is caused by an ID being used more than once. To fix this, you can implement an `#after_build` callback that ensures the upload fields will have unique IDs.

To summarize...

**Add an `#after_build` callback to the `managed_file` field:**

```
$num_docs = 3;

// Build the number of name fieldsets indicated by $form_state['num_docs'].
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_docs; $i++) {
  $form['managed_file'][$i] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'Managed File' . $i,
    '#progress_indicator' => 'throbber',
    '#progress_message' => 'Upload successful!',
    "#upload_validators"  => array("file_validate_extensions" => array("doc")),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://doc/',
    '#after_build' => array("MODULE_file_managed_fix_duplicate_id"),
  );
}

$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
);
```

**Create the following callback:**

```
function MODULE_file_managed_fix_duplicate_id($element) {
  if ($element['#id'] === $element['upload']['#id']) {
    $element['#id'] = drupal_html_id($element['#id']);
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Once I did that and cleared all my caches, the javascript errors went away and the error messages starting working.